# Data in SQL wont sync with Linq DataContext using traditional SQL syntax

Tags: sql, linq

I perform selects with linq to sql in my app and other things (insert,update,delete) by traditional sql syntax.

But, when I insert or delete something, my datacontext doesn't update. So, if I search for the ID of selected object, an empty query returns. I checked the DB and I'm sure that sql syntax works fine.

In short, when I do something with my DB with sql syntax it changes my db but not the DataContext instance!

Comment: Can you provide some code? Are you sure you need raw SQL to perform the requested task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Linq to Sql you should do all operations with that,It means if you want to do some raw Sql still you should use Linq to Sql syntax if not your link to data base won't update.
So I switched to Linq to Sql completely.
Thanks All

Useful info : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-1-introduction-and-model.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you saving the data?  E.g. calling `Context.SaveChanges()` or whatever the equivalent is?

Comment: I tried this method for saving data but It didn't work :(
db.SubmitChanges();
db is my DataContext variable.

Answer (score 0):

Link to SQL DataContext have a cache system. Look at the DataContext.Refresh method group for methods to refresh your entities. Another simple solution is to reinstanciate your DataContext after doing some raw SQL.

Comment: I tried this , but it didn't work :
db.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues,db.tbl_substances);
db is my DataContext variable .
Is it what u mean by refreshing ?